# How to UV map low res textures.

Tags: texturing, uv

So what I want to know is how to UV map low resolution textures. When I was exporting my UV layout it said the size of the UV layout was going to be 1024x1024 but I need the textures on my model to be 64x64. I was wondering if I put my 64x64 textures inside this 1024x1024 UV map in an external image editor then re-imported that UV map with my textures, would that keep my textures 64x64? I doubted that so that's why I'm here asking how to UV map low res textures. I'm new to using blender so sorry if this is a really nooby question.

Answer (score 3):

I think what Duarte was trying to say is that the resolution of the textures doesn't matter for the UV layout. UV coordinates are bound to the mesh, not to the texture.

You can create a 1024x1024 texture in blender, then resize it in whatever image manipulation software you use. For example I tend to create quite hi-res textures (4k and above) in blender, baking them and later resizing them in gimp to whatever size the final result should have. The only problem is that you are losing detail on your texture map, the UV layout fits perfectly, though.

Comment: Ok so, if I export the UV layout and then in an external image editing program I move my 64x64 textures to fit inside the uv layout image, the textures will still be 64x64? So when I export the UV layout, all it really is, is a reference for me when I'm in a image editor? Of course, I delete the reference uv layout after I'm done positioning my textures so they fit inside the UV layout.

Comment: Just scale down the 1024x1024 texture to 64x64. No scaling, no moving around.

Comment: The textures I'm using are already 64x64, i placed the 64x64 textures on top of the 1024x1024 uv map. If i were to scale down the 1024x1024 uv map with my 64x64 textures on it  they would be way to blurry afterward. Sorry if this is getting annoying.

Comment: Maybe you could post a screenshot? 64x64 is quite a small size for textures. Since this size doesn't contain much pixels the result will be blurry and it has nothing to do with the UV layout.

A diffuse texture is a digital image, nothing more. If you would downscale a photo (reduce its size from 4k to 128X64 pixels) it would also be blurred if you try to upscale it again.

Comment: http://imgur.com/8jYP6Qq

Comment: What I need is the textures inside the UV map to stay 64x64, now I know they will stay 64x64 but if I use the uv map for a reference and then save that file the textures will be saved in a 1024x1024 image and I can't have that. So should I upscale the 64x64 textures to 1024x1024 then apply those textures to the 1024x1024 uv map then down scale the entire UV map 10 64x64

Comment: also do you know how to export an obj file from blender with your textures on it?

Comment: One again: You don't "scale" uv maps, you scale texture images. UVs are bound to the mesh.

Create the 1024X1024 texture in blender, open it in gimp or whatever you use, scale it down to 64x64. 

If you hand-paint it. I'd suggest you wait with the downscale until you're done with painting. If you want to bake something in blender, bake it to 1024x1024 then scale it down.

Sry, I really don't get the problem with it....

Answer (score 1):

From my limited experience with UV unwrapping exported UV layouts are purely for reference purposes while creating your texture, you don't "re-import" them to Blender.

Texture coordinates (or the UV layout) is stored inside Blender on the mesh itself, the 1024x1024 image you export is used only for knowing what goes where while creating/painting your texture in whatever graphics editing program you want to use.

You can directly create a new image with whatever resolution you need (higher or lower) and use it as texture inside Blender without worrying about image size.

UV coordinates automatically adjust to whatever image size you choose, you only have to be careful to keep the same image aspect ratio so that your texture wont be stretched. As long as you maintain the same width and height proportion it should be fine.

Just  create a new 64x64 image, paint your texture vaguely respecting the exported UV layout (you can overlay it for reference) so that it matches the correct parts of the mesh.